# How to get youtube api json response - android

Tags: java, android, json, youtube-api

I am trying to get the json response of Youtube API v3 but for some reason I get response code 404. I copy the link to my browser and I can view the result just fine. I don't know what I am doing wrong, here is the code:

```
try
    {
        URL url = new URL(query);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        int respCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

        if (respCode == 200) {
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            //String response = convertStreamToString(in);
        }

        urlConnection.disconnect();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

This is the query string:

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=%22=test%22&type=video&key=myapikey

Answer (score 0):

I create a HTTPHandler class...

```
public class HttpHandler {

private static final String TAG = HttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();

public HttpHandler() {
}

public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
    String response = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        // read the response
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        response = convertStreamToString(in);
        in.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return response;
}

private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

To use it, I create a new HTTPHandler

```
HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
String url = URL_API;
String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
```

From there, I can parse through jsonStr and get my information.

This works for me....

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve this issue by adding:

```
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(false);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: First of all the `setRequestProperty` is deprecated so I suggest against using this. Also I have tried out the code from your original post and the response I get is a 400 (meaning a bad request). This is also what I'm getting when opening the same URL from my browser. I do not see any 404, so what was the problem in the first place?

Comment: @Aris its probably a bad request because you are missing peramters... API KEY, etc.

Comment: @DroiDev I know that. The problem is that the OP is mentioning a 404, they seem incapable of understanding HTTP codes. Also their answer posted above does actually answer their original problem. They need to understand what is going on.